# How do I include javascript/jquery image resizing with wordpress?

Tags: jquery, javascript, images

I wan't to include this script in my wordpress theme, making it resize all of the images inside posts according to the current window height:

https://github.com/gutierrezalex/photo-resize

I've made a basic test page in my text editor and it resizes the image just fine. However, when I try to apply/include it in my wordpress theme I simply can't get it to work.

Comment: "I simply can't get it to work" --> Any error messages? [Debugging info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)? What does the JS console say?

Answer (score 2):

Download the script (or add it via [npm](http://npmjs.org/) > [bower](http://bower.io/) to your theme), [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) it at the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook and then simply add/enqueue another (your custom) script where you add the contents of the [demo index.html](https://github.com/gutierrezalex/photo-resize/blob/master/index.html) file:

```
( function( $ ) {
    $( "img" ).photoResize( {
        bottomSpacing: 15
    } );
} )( jQuery || {} );
```